# Error in module.fit_generator with Keras. Wrong number of channels given

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I'm trying to train a kidney segmentation network on medical images.
Whenever I try to compile my network model, it gives me this warning: "NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3, or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (1947, 352, 352, 2) (2 channels)."

The shape of my X_Train are n_slice_train,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_CHANNELS.

The shape of my Y_Train (mask) are n_slice_train, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, NUM_CLASSES.

IMG_CHANNELS = 3

NUM_CLASSES = 2

```py
dataset_name = "data"

# I want to train a network that takes a 512x512x3 (rgb) image as input
# and the respective segmentation mask (0: background, 255: lesion)
IMG_WIDTH = 352     
IMG_HEIGHT = 352
IMG_CHANNELS = 3
NUM_CLASSES = 2
hu_min = -100
hu_max = 400

n_slice_train = sum(volumes_train_info["Num_slice_selected"])
n_slice_val = sum(volumes_val_info["Num_slice_selected"])

train_vol = os.listdir(path_train_vol)
val_vol = os.listdir(path_val_vol)
train_mask = os.listdir(path_train_mask)
val_mask = os.listdir(path_val_mask)

X_train = np.zeros((n_slice_train,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y_train = np.zeros((n_slice_train,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,NUM_CLASSES), dtype=np.float32)
desired_spacing = 1 # mm/px
volumes_train_info["New_PixelSpacing"] = {}
i = 0          
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_vol), total=len(train_vol)):                 
  
  case_name = str(id_) 
  Vol = np.load(path_train_vol+'/'+case_name)

  old_spacing = volumes_train_info["PixelSpacing_x"][n]
  Vol, new_spacing = preprocess_vol(Vol, desired_spacing, old_spacing,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH, hu_min, hu_max)
  volumes_train_info["New_PixelSpacing"][n] = new_spacing
  for s in range(len(Vol)): 
    X_train[i] = Vol[s,:,:,:] 
    i += 1
     
j = 0          
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_mask), total=len(train_mask)): 

  case_name = str(id_) 

  Mask = np.load(path_train_mask+'/'+case_name)
  old_spacing = volumes_train_info["PixelSpacing_x"][n]
  Mask = preprocess_seg(Mask, desired_spacing, old_spacing,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH)

  for s in range(len(Mask)):
    mask = Mask[s,:,:]
    mask = to_categorical(mask, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, dtype='float32') 
    Y_train[j] = mask 
    j += 1

X_val = np.zeros((n_slice_val,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_CHANNELS), dtype=np.uint8)
Y_val= np.zeros((n_slice_val,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_HEIGHT,NUM_CLASSES), dtype=np.float32)
i = 0          
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(val_vol), total=len(val_vol)): 

  case_name = str(id_) 
  Vol = np.load(path_val_vol+'/'+case_name)

  old_spacing = volumes_val_info["PixelSpacing_x"][n]
  Vol, new_spacing = preprocess_vol(Vol, desired_spacing, old_spacing,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH, hu_min, hu_max)
  volumes_val_info["New_PixelSpacing"][n] = new_spacing
  for s in range(len(Vol)): 
    X_val[i] = Vol[s,:,:,:]
    i = i + 1
     
j = 0        
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(val_mask), total=len(val_mask)): 

  case_name = str(id_) 
  Mask = np.load(path_val_mask+'/'+case_name)
  old_spacing = volumes_val_info["PixelSpacing_x"][n]
  Mask = preprocess_seg(Mask, desired_spacing, old_spacing,IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH)
  for s in range(len(Mask)):
    mask = Mask[s,:,:]
    mask = to_categorical(mask, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, dtype='float32') 
    Y_val[j] = mask 
    j = j + 1

# Data augmentation (training set)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 3,
                                   width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True,
                                   vertical_flip = False,
                                   fill_mode = 'nearest')

# Data augmentation (validation set)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

# Generator
seed = 1
def XYaugmentGenerator(X1, y, seed, batch_size):
    genX1 = image_datagen.flow(X1, y, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
    genX2 = image_datagen.flow(y, X1, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
    while True:
        X1i = genX1.next()
        X2i = genX2.next()
        yield X1i[0], X2i[0] 
BACKBONE = 'resnet34' 
model = Unet(backbone_name=BACKBONE,
            input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,IMG_CHANNELS), 
            encoder_weights='imagenet', 
            encoder_freeze=False,
            decoder_block_type='transpose',
            classes=NUM_CLASSES,
            activation='sigmoid')
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.00001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy']) # scegliamo un learning rate di 10e-5
n_slice_train = X_train.shape[0] 
n_slice_val = X_val.shape[0] 
batch_size = 1  
n_epochs = 20

# Checkpoint definition
csv_logger = CSVLogger('./log.out', append=True, separator=';')
earlystopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',   
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=2,
                              verbose=0, 
                              mode='auto')   
filepath="model_2D_v5-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
modelcheckpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath,
                                  monitor="val_loss",
                                  verbose = 1, 
                                  save_best_only=True) 
      

callbacks_list = [csv_logger, earlystopping, modelcheckpoint]

# Train model
results = model.fit_generator(XYaugmentGenerator(X_train,Y_train,seed, batch_size), 
                              steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(float(n_slice_train)/float(batch_size)),
                              validation_data = val_datagen.flow(X_val,Y_val,batch_size), 
                              validation_steps = np.ceil(float(n_slice_val)/float(batch_size)),
                              shuffle = True,
                              epochs = n_epochs,
                              callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

Traceback:

````
        Epoch 1/20
        /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/numpy_array_iterator.py:136: UserWarning:
        
        NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3, or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (1947, 352, 352, 2) (2 channels).
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 204s 105ms/step - loss: 0.5873 - binary_accuracy: 0.8081 - val_loss: 0.3755 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9714
        
        Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.37554, saving model to model_2D_v4-01-0.38.hdf5
        Epoch 2/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 184s 94ms/step - loss: 0.2442 - binary_accuracy: 0.9804 - val_loss: 0.1517 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9843
        
        Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.37554 to 0.15170, saving model to model_2D_v4-02-0.15.hdf5
        Epoch 3/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 182s 94ms/step - loss: 0.1039 - binary_accuracy: 0.9907 - val_loss: 0.0701 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9929
        
        Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 0.15170 to 0.07014, saving model to model_2D_v4-03-0.07.hdf5
        Epoch 4/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 183s 94ms/step - loss: 0.0492 - binary_accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.0311 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9950
        
        Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 0.07014 to 0.03110, saving model to model_2D_v4-04-0.03.hdf5
        Epoch 5/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 182s 94ms/step - loss: 0.0260 - binary_accuracy: 0.9957 - val_loss: 0.0202 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9960
        
        Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.03110 to 0.02020, saving model to model_2D_v4-05-0.02.hdf5
        Epoch 6/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 183s 94ms/step - loss: 0.0153 - binary_accuracy: 0.9959 - val_loss: 0.0412 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9943
        
        Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 0.02020
        Epoch 7/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 183s 94ms/step - loss: 0.0104 - binary_accuracy: 0.9961 - val_loss: 0.0200 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9955
        
        Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 0.02020 to 0.02004, saving model to model_2D_v4-07-0.02.hdf5
        Epoch 8/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 186s 96ms/step - loss: 0.0075 - binary_accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.0048 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9958
        
        Epoch 00008: val_loss improved from 0.02004 to 0.00476, saving model to model_2D_v4-08-0.00.hdf5
        Epoch 9/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 193s 99ms/step - loss: 0.0060 - binary_accuracy: 0.9964 - val_loss: 6.1250e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9962
        
        Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 0.00476 to 0.00061, saving model to model_2D_v4-09-0.00.hdf5
        Epoch 10/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 192s 99ms/step - loss: 0.0051 - binary_accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.0119 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9961
        
        Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.00061
        Epoch 11/20
        1947/1947 [==============================] - 192s 99ms/step - loss: 0.0047 - binary_accuracy: 0.9966 - val_loss: 0.0083 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9968
        
        Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.00061```
````

Comment: Please add code and full traceback.

Comment: Hello I added code and traceback complete, missing some functions because they are on other scripts but I think they should not be necessary to understand what is the problem